# Magento 2.4.6 Paypal Braintree error when adding item to cart

Tags: paypal, braintree, magento2.4.6

Magento 2.4.6 Paypal Braintree error when adding item to cart 'display on shopping cart'(Paypal button) is enabled.  Once you disable you are able to add items to cart and checkout.

update-fresh install i was able to duplicate.

Enable Braintree payments.

Enable PayPal through Braintree.

Display on shopping cart-'yes'  500 error
display on shopping cart-'no'  no error, able to add to cart and proceed.

https://magento-967393-3381519.cloudwaysapps.com/

https://magento-967393-3381519.cloudwaysapps.com/checkout/cart/

currently set to Display on shopping cart-'yes'

Rich

Answer (score 2):

Found this that answers my above issue.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37242

After consultation, I have learned that the Braintree V4.5.0 module in M2.4.6 includes new functionality and is now passing individual cart line items to PayPal. Previously, the Braintree V4.4.0 version in M2.4.5 and earlier did NOT pass cart line items to PayPal just the Grand Total amount on the order. However, there is an issue in that when the cart line items do not add up to the Grand Total, for example if there is a separate sales tax line item, then PayPal through Braintree will fail as a payment method on checkout, the modal box will automatically close and Magento will display an error message to the customer "PayPal Checkout could not be initialized."

There is a configuration option found under Advanced Braintree Settings for Send Cart Line Items, which defaults to Yes. Setting "Send Cart Line Items" = NO does allow the PayPal login modal box to zoom out and remain... it is possible to login to PayPal using the modal box, but upon clicking the "Complete Purchase" button, the modal box closes and returns to the Magento checkout flow where a pink box declares "Something went wrong with your request. Please try again later." simultaneously an error for "Call to undefined method..." is logged in exception.log file.

** main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtension::getGwBasePrice() in /www/releases/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/Gateway/Request/Level23ProcessingDataBuilder.php:188 **

As of now, there is no workaround that allows checkout using PayPal through Braintree on M2.4.6

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps as I've had the same thing.

On [magento github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37242) somebody suggested the following:

*This issue seems to stem for the "Gift Wrapping" Section within
/Magento/vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/Gateway/Request/Level23ProcessingDataBuilder.php*

*Commenting out lines 186-189 & 198-232 allows PayPal via Braintree to process without errors*

*Under Advanced Braintree Setttings "Send Cart Lines" Should be set to NO, if items are not being added to the mini-cart*

Basically, quote out these lines:

```
        $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
        $gwBasePrice = $this->numberToString($extensionAttributes->getGwBasePrice(), 2);
        $gwItemsBasePrice = $this->numberToString($extensionAttributes->getGwItemsBasePrice(), 2);
```

These

```
        if ($gwBasePrice > 0) {
            $gwBasePriceItems[] = [
                'name' => 'Gift Wrapping for Order',
                'kind' => TransactionLineItem::DEBIT,
                'quantity' => 1.00,
                'unitAmount' => $gwBasePrice,
                'totalAmount' => $gwBasePrice
            ];

            $lineItems = array_merge($lineItems, $gwBasePriceItems);
        }
```

And these

```
         if ($gwItemsBasePrice > 0) {
            $gwItemsBasePriceItems[] = [
                'name' => 'Gift Wrapping for Items',
                'kind' => TransactionLineItem::DEBIT,
                'quantity' => 1.00,
                'unitAmount' => $gwItemsBasePrice,
                'totalAmount' => $gwItemsBasePrice
            ];

            $lineItems = array_merge($lineItems, $gwItemsBasePriceItems);
        }
```

Someone also [supplied a patch](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37242#issuecomment-1541797057) in the same page